# ¿ Como le indico al IDE wxDev-C++ que mi proyecto consta de varios archivos, para que los enlace todos?

Tags: c, enlazado

Según las especificaciones del proyecto que tengo que desarrollar, el código de constar de un main.c y dos librerías, una para definir y manipular las Estructuras de Datos(ED) y la otra para tratar las cadenas(La librería de los ED necesita hacer uso de la librería de las cadenas). Pues bien, en el main hago el include de las 2 librerias y en los .h sigo la siguiente estructura:

```
#ifndef CADENA_H
#define CADENA_H

#include <stdio.h>
...
...
...

bool compararCadenas(char cadena1[], char cadena2[]);
...
...
...

#endif
```

Y luego en los .h defino en si cada función. Pues bien, cuando compilo me saltan errores del tipo [Linker Error] undefined reference to `ejemploFuncion'. La cosa esta en que me saltan varios errores de este tipo pero no de todas las funciones de la librería aunque si están definidas todas.

En el IDE puedo ver los comandos que se ejecutan; son estos:

> Compilador: Default GCC compiler
> Building Makefile: "D:\MisArchivos\Universidad\UMH\Primer_Curso\Primer_Cuatrimestre\Programación\Segunda_Matricula\Septiembre\Proyecto\Makefile.win"
> Ejecutando make...
> mingw32-make.exe -f "Makefile.win" all
> g++.exe -c cadenas.c -o Objects/MingW/cadenas.o -I"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" -I"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/" -I"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/include/common" -g3
>
> cadenas.c: In function 'char* TransformaNumSerie(int)':
> cadenas.c:276:10: warning: address of local variable 'cfecha' returned [enabled by default]
>
> g++.exe "Objects/MingW/main.o" "Objects/MingW/cadenas.o" "Objects/MingW/datos.o" -o "Output/MingW/P_FP_Sep.exe" -L"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/lib/wx/gcc_lib" -L"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/lib" -L"D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib" -g3
>
> Objects/MingW/main.o: In function `main':<br> D:\MisArchivos\Universidad\UMH\Primer_Curso\Primer_Cuatrimestre\Programación\Segunda_Matricula\Septiembre\Proyecto/main.c:62: undefined reference to` esFecha
>
> ...

Parece que **si** está enlazando todos los archivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución que he encontrado gracias al usuario @Trauma ha sido hacer un Rebuild All(recompilar todo) para que el archivo makefile se diera cuenta de los cambios efectuados en el resto de archivos. Se ve que es un fallo extraño que no suele ocurrir pero gracias a la comunidad de StackOverflow lo he podido solucionar en muy poco tiempo.